# .NET Core Hosted Service Logging LogLevel in Environment Variable

Tags: logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I created a hosted service with the following code:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            await new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                    {
                        configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "SAMPLEHOST_");
                        configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
                    })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddHostedService<SampleHostedService>();
                        services.AddHostedService<AnotherHostedService>();
                    })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => 
                    {
                        logging.AddConsole();
                    })
                .RunConsoleAsync();
        }
    }
```

...having the following `launchsettings.json`.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "SampleHost.Cli": {
      "environmentVariables": {
        "LOGGING__LOGLEVEL__DEFAULT": "Debug",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to make this appear in my console. :(

`Logger.LogDebug("Hello debug");`

I want modify and tweak the `LogLevel` purely on environment variable. Did I missed anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => 
{
    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    logging.AddConsole();
})
```

Comment: My first try this didn't work, but modifying my environment variable to `"SAMPLEHOST_LOGGING__LOGLEVEL__DEFAULT": "Debug"` worked. Have to note not to forget the prefix. Thanks for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with hosted services, so I don't know will this help, but, I did work on ASP.NET app, and had added this to **appsettings**.json.

```
  "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning",
    "System": "Error",
    "Microsoft": "Error"
   },
   "Console": {
    "IncludeScopes": true
   }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I specified that this should be done with Environment Variable.